# How can we implement negative mulitiplier in a autolayout constraint?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to get a negative proportional value of another view's height to set top of my view. But negative multiplier is not allowed in xib.

Comment: What do you mean by negative multiplier ? Whats the scenario?

Comment: Can't you simply sea the first and second attributes in the constraint?

Comment: Did you solve it? I tried to set manually and it throws the view to an unexpected place

Answer (score 0):

Negative multipliers values don't make sense. Can you please specify why you need negative multiplier in the first case. Meanwhile you can work with negative constant values to achieve the desired design. Happy Coding.

Comment: View1 is above view 2. I want to set the      top of view1 proportional to height of view2. The final result should be negative to set the top.

Comment: please share a screenshot for clarity